# Java synchronized block not working as expected

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to implement a thread block using a map so that no more than one operation can be handled on a single customer at a time. This is talking to a web service and requires multiple steps to accomplish the full workflow. I need to be able to lock on a single customer at a time but allow other threads to execute without blocking the flow.

Here is my test cases to see how to get it working. What I am seeing is that the second thread cannot do get into the synchronized block of `doSynchronizedSomething` until the first thread has cleared. I thought this should work, but it is not working as expected.

Here are the results and you will notice that the millis are three seconds apart. I also checked to make sure that the `CustomerLocks` are not the same object in my test case. Is this possible?

```
Starting operation 123456 at time 1381173121688
Done with operation for 123456 at time 1381173124689
Starting operation 234567 at time 1381173124689
Done with operation for 234567 at time 1381173127690
```

Code

```
    package simplethreadlock;

    public class CustomerLock {

        private String customerId;

        public CustomerLock(String customerId) {

        }

        public String getCustomerId() {
            return customerId;
        }

        public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
            this.customerId = customerId;
        }
    }


    package simplethreadlock;

    import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

    public class CustomerLockingMap {


        private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, CustomerLock> locks = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, CustomerLock>();

        public static CustomerLock aquireLock(String customerId) {
            CustomerLock lock = locks.get(customerId);
            if (lock == null) {
                lock = new CustomerLock(customerId);
                locks.put(customerId, lock);
            }
            return lock; 
        }
    }


    package simplethreadlock;

    import org.junit.Assert;
    import org.junit.Test;

    public class CutomerLockingTest {

    @Test
    public void testLock() throws InterruptedException {
        final String customerId1 = "123456";
        final String customerId2 = "234567";

        final CustomerLock customer1Lock1 = CustomerLockingMap
                .aquireLock(customerId1);
        final CustomerLock customer1Lock2 = CustomerLockingMap
                .aquireLock(customerId1);

        final CustomerLock customer2Lock1 = CustomerLockingMap
                .aquireLock(customerId2);
        final CustomerLock customer2Lock2 = CustomerLockingMap
                .aquireLock(customerId2);

         CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        Assert.assertNotEquals(customer1Lock1, customer2Lock1);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {

                    doSynchronziedSomething(customer1Lock1, customerId1);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();


        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    doSynchronziedSomething(customer2Lock1, customerId2);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }).start();


        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    doSynchronziedSomething(customer1Lock2, customerId1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();


        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {

                    doSynchronziedSomething(customer2Lock2, customerId2);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }).start();

        latch.await(8, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

        private void doSynchronziedSomething(final CustomerLock lock, final String customerId) throws InterruptedException {
            synchronized (lock) {
                System.out.println("Starting operation " + customerId + " at time "
                        + System.currentTimeMillis());
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                System.out.println("Done with operation for " + customerId
                        + " at time " + System.currentTimeMillis());
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit**

Silly me it is Thread.start() but if you are looking at the example for help on this I did add the CountDownLatch so that the unit test will not exit before the threads have had time to finish.

Comment: `.run()` or `.start()`!?

Comment: Thanks you rock!!!!! That was stupid on my part. I will gladly click your solution if you want to post the answer.

Comment: I was wondering why I didn't need the latch to wait for the threads to finish.

Comment: because your threads didn't have concurrency

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Thread#run()` is a normal synchronous method call. What you want is `Thread#start()` which executes a `native` call to start the OS thread.

Answer (score 5):

```
someThread.run()
```

is not a way to start a thread. It only runs that thread's internal runnable within the current thread, before any subsequent lines. Use `.start()` to actually start the thread as a thread, and let the two threads(and main thread) run simultaneously.